# Re-creating an Azure runbook

Tags: azure, runbook

We want to change an Azure Runbook from being a PowerShell workflow to being a stock standard PowerShell script. We need to keep the same name as we have other runbooks that call this one.

Unfortunately you can't just change the runbook type. So we have to delete and re-create with the same name. Which works, until you click Edit to enter the script.
The Editor blade opens, but with a big dark grey "Deleted" bar across the screen. It won't allow you to edit the text.

So we now have an empty runbook that lots of scripts need to reference. How do I get my new script into the portal without creating a runbook with a new name?